# Ionic 2 How to bind a dynamically added div text to model?

Tags: model, ionic2, bind, directive

What I need to accomplish is to have a ion-input binded to model, but displaying a formatted value while keeping the raw value in model.

Text-mask does not apply here as afaik, it would transform the raw value too.

So I went to a solution where I put a directive on ion-input, which hide the child input and insert a div which will contain the formatted value.

Everything works fine, except that if model is modified elsewhere, the div is not updated automatically.

Question: how to bind dynamically the div to model (with call to a formatNumber function)?

I have explored some "observable" ways, but with no success...

Here is a (simplified) sample of code I use to manage the input and the div...

home.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Label</ion-label>
    <ion-input item-content myDirective [(ngModel)]="data.field01"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

home.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    @Input() data;
  constructor() {
        this.data = {
            field01: 100000
        }
  }
}
```

myDirective.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
    host: {
        '(click)': 'onClick()'
    }
})
export class MyDirective {
  public formattedValue: string;
  constructor( private elemRef: ElementRef,
                             private renderer: Renderer
                         ) {
  }
    ngOnInit() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            let myInput = this.elemRef.nativeElement.children[0];
            this.myInput.hidden = 'true';
            let myDiv = document.createElement("div");
            this.myDiv.className = this.myInput.className;
            this.myDiv.innerText = 'mydiv';
            this.elemRef.nativeElement.appendChild(this.myDiv)
        }, 0);
    }
    onClick() {
            this.showPicker();
    }
    ...
}
```

Additional info:

- input value is edited through a custom picker I don't have put here
  => works fine
- when picker is closed, formatted value is applied to myDiv directly by picker => works fine

Comment: I would suggest using a [pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) not a directive

Comment: it seems that we can not use a pipe on an input. Am I wrong?